# Using npm to only install the packages needed in current project

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I am just starting  with node/npm and I have a lot of trouble with

1. the path to install the package
2. loading the package in node

I would like to have a package folder (no matter its path) with only the packages needed for my current project (I don't use a `package.json` just the normal `npm install...`).  So instead of installing the package in the folder given by `npm root`, I thought I would install all the packages in a local folder with `npm install --prefix  ./node_modules  pck_name`.

If I install the packages globally, I am able to load the packages in Node with `require('pck-nam')`, but when I install in the local folder, I am unable to load the package in Node even by adding the folder path to `node_path` or with the full path of the packages in `require`:

```
const pck =  require('C:/Users/Me/myproject/my_modules/node_modules/pck-name');
```

The error is  `Cannot find module 'pck-name'`

Because I was stuck on this for a long time without finding a solution, I though of renaming the folder given by `npm root` and then doing a global install : because the folder is will be recreated from scratch, then I will just have the packages for my project. But after the install, I did `npm list`, and all my previous package are listed, including the one for current project.

I have read many questions/answers and many tuto but I am still unable to use npm/node the way I would like (I am used to python and I regularly use import for global/local modules so I may be thinking too much in a python way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can at least partially answer my question as I understand know why the previous package where still there after I renamed the folder. Although I didn't install from a `package.json`, `npm install` do create a `package.json`, or in my case a `package-lock.json`. And apparently when running a `npm install package-name` it will check `package-lock.json` re-install all the missing packages.

So it's not enough to rename the folder indicated by `npm root`, I also add to rename the `package-lock.json`. Now I am clear. I still think that I haven't found the best way to go but at least I have what I need.